# Suitable Doctrine relational mapping

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, one-to-one

I have two Doctrine entities: **Orders** and **OrderStatus**.
The one **Orders** record can handle **only** one status (for example, `processing` or `processed` or `confirmation` or `inactive` or enything else).
But the **OrderStatus** record may handle many different orders.

Which the best mapping should I use?
Could is it be right way to use `one-to-one unidirectional` for the **Orders** and `many-to-many unidirectional` for the **OrderStatus**?

I use YML mapping configuration.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Orders entity can have 1 status, and the OrderStatus can have many Orders, then this is a basic one-to-many.

```
OrderStatus:
  type: entity
  oneToMany:
    orders:
      targetEntity: Order
      mappedBy: orderStatus

Order:
  type: entity
  manyToOne:
    orderStatus:
      targetEntity: OrderStatus
      inversedBy: orders
      joinColumn:
        name: orderStatus_id
        referencedColumnName: id
```

I recommend naming your entity Order, instead of Orders. Since symfony can work its magical pluralization and getters-setters. I think the way you have it, there might be errors with the methods and the mapping.

Also, check out the [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) for doctrine mapping

Comment: Yes, I've tried to create an Order entity by command-line: `php app/console generate:doctrine:entity --with-repository --entity=AcmeMyBundle:Order` but it was an error because `Order` is reserved word. Anyway, thank you for the answer!